# Why did wheat become the dominant food culture?

Tags: food, agriculture

Growing wheat, rice and other cereals is very labor-intensive.
Wheat has very small edible mass compared to the other tissues.
Wheat is very weather-dependent.

Why were other cultures not used instead?

For instance, dandelions are abundant everywhere, do not require any labor, grow well in all weather and all their parts are edible.

[image]

Comment: Interesting....+1

Comment: Ever tried to eat dandilions?  They're really only edible in the spring, before they flower (dandilion greens), otherwise they're very bitter.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is both too broad and primarily opinion based.  It asks for a hypothetical speculative comparison stripped of any historical content.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a history question.

Comment: If this is not the historical question, then I must say this **history** site will be full of crackpots who are only concerned with too specific issues. **History of major diet**, why not???

Comment: Only what the questioners should have asked is not the comparison with dandelion, but rather with rice, potatoes, corns etc.

Comment: But the questioner is not asking about the history of Old World diet, but about "why not? (negative what if)". Asking about "Why did agricultural societies the world over choose the plants they did and not something else?" is a trifle broad.

Answer (score 5):

About the particular example:
Wheat and other grains have high nutrition value and dandelions not. You need to eat several kilo of dandelion to cover your basic calorie needs. 40Cal/100g, that is 400Cal /kg. You need to eat 5 kg if you are an office worker sitting all the day. But most probably you would be pretty sick in the first day if you can finish that, and you wouldn't be able to digest even that amount of calory due to the enormous amount of fiber it has in it.

Also, dandelion do not grow everywhere, hard to collect, even harder to store. Most leafy veggies are originally poisonous, and needed domestication + cooking to make them edible. Wheat, corn etc are practically grass. Saying that dandelion is more common than grass is kind of arguable.

All agricultural society based on domestication of grains and starchy roots/vegetables. Corn, potato, rice, wheat, malt etc. For the simple reason people needed calorie and protein. Dandelion has neither. Those people were not looking for loosing weight fast or something healthy and hipster to eat with their pizza. They were looking for survival.

Comment: Have you counted raw dandelions or dried up and have you taken into account its roots?

Comment: All nutrition data is on raw dandelion leaf. I couldn't find data on root with Google. Please, include some link if you find anything.

Comment: Dandelion root appears to be about 3.4 Kcal/gram

Comment: @ConradTurner Any reference?

Comment: I would treat most things on [this site](http://nutrition.healthgrove.com/l/21327/AHPA-Dandelion-Root) with caution. Doing some further digging (so to speak) I am inclined not to trust it as it as it is so much higher than most other [root vegetables](http://www.caloriecount.com/calories-root-vegetables-ic1107) which are down around 0.25-1 kcal/gram. Though it seems to be consistent with raw cassava so not impossible.

Comment: @ConradTurner Let's set aside that the most common Goolge search for "dandelion root" is weight loss, and most recepies are found are teas not food. It can happen that all those people are wrong, actually often happens with popular diets. However 3.9 Cal/gram is the cal content of PURE SUGAR! Also, according to that link 35 g out of 100g is fiber, which is hell of a lot.

Comment: According to USDA Handbook #8, and every decent source on vegetarian nutrition, the primary virtue of grains is that they contain high amounts of protein, though not complete protein. Dandelions contain none, and I personally question whether a human digestion system can get anywhere near the test-tube nutrition listed. Our relatively short intestines are not well-built for getting everything out of coarse greenery, unlike a gorilla intestine.

Comment: Neolithic revolution developed a diet for virtual vegetarianism with occasional animal product input. Complete protein requires grain + legume, grain + tree nut, or legume + tree nut, & protein is required every day in a healthy diet. So successful human diets always require meat/eggs/milk &c, or grains/legumes/tree nuts. Grains & legumes could be made to grow most quickly over the largest acreage, and are the basis of diet worldwide. (Yes, quinoa is the complete protein grain, but it's a freak & didn't spread until recently.)